# How to get all column's first values of consecutive groups and also max of different bins of the respective group in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe as :
[pandas dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1FWe.png)

I'm consecutively grouping by '**Name**' column for *total counts, consecutive counts* & for '**Age**' column I'm applying *min, max* to generate dataframe as :
[image: groupby & min, max, total count, cons count]

Then, I'm getting only *first value of every column* for each consecutive group as :
[image: first values]

Then, I'm trying to get all column values where *max* '**Age**' between *5-20* from each consecutive group is present and then, I'm trying to concat this dataframe with the dataframe which has *first values*. But I got the output as :
[image: concat df]

But the expected output is :

[image: expected output]

Also, this is for a single bin i.e., *5-20*, how to include for **more** than 1 bins, for example, if 1 bin is *5-20* & next bin is *25-40*, the expected output is :
[image: more bins output]

For above outputs, this is the code what I have written :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# initialize list of lists
data = [['tom', 10], ['tom', 5], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14], ['tom', 20],['tom', 10], ['tom', 10], ['juli', 17], ['tom', 30], ['nick', 19], ['juli', 24], ['juli', 29],['tom', 0], ['juli', 76]]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])


# print dataframe.
print("df = ",df)
print("")

# acquire min, max, count, consecutive same names
df['min'] = df.groupby(df['Name'].ne(df['Name'].shift()).cumsum())['Age'].transform('min')#df.groupby("Name",sort=False)['Age'].transform('min')
df['max'] = df.groupby(df['Name'].ne(df['Name'].shift()).cumsum())['Age'].transform('max')#df.groupby("Name",sort=False)['Age'].transform('max')
df['count'] = df.groupby("Name",sort=False)['Name'].transform('count')
df['cons'] = df.groupby(df['Name'].ne(df['Name'].shift()).cumsum())['Name'].transform('size')

print(df)

# take the first column values of every consecutive group
df_t = df
temp_df=df.groupby(df['Name'].ne(df['Name'].shift()).cumsum(),as_index=False)[df.columns].agg('first')

print("")
print("temp_df = ",temp_df)

df_t = df_t.reset_index()
df_t = df_t.drop(['index'], axis=1)
print("df_t = ", df_t)

# check max of bin 5-20 for every consecutive group
df_t1 = df_t.groupby(df_t['Name'].ne(df_t['Name'].shift()).cumsum(),as_index=False).apply(lambda  x:x['Age'][(x['Age'] >= 5) & (x['Age'] < 20)].agg(lambda y : y.idxmax()))
print("")
print("df_t1 = ", df_t1)

# checking for condition if value is np array
a = df_t1.tolist()
b=[]
c = np.array([2])
c = c.astype('int64')
for i in a:
    if type(i)== type(c[0]):
        b.append(i)
    else:
        continue

df_t1 = df_t.iloc[b]
print("")
print("output df_t1 = ", df_t1)

# concat the bin max and first value df
concatdf = pd.concat([temp_df, df_t1],axis=1)
print("")
print("concatdf = ", concatdf)
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can greatly simplify your code by doing a single `groupby` for almost all indicators excepts the cumulated count.

Then just mask your data according to your criterion and concatenate.

I believe this is doing what you want:

```
group = df['Name'].ne(df['Name'].shift()).cumsum()

df2 = (df
   .groupby(group, as_index=False)
   .agg(**{'Name': ('Name', 'first'),
           'Age': ('Age', 'first'),
           'min': ('Age', 'min'),
           'max': ('Age', 'max'),
           'cons': ('Age', 'count')
            })
   .assign(count=lambda d: d.groupby('Name')['cons'].transform('sum'))
)

out = pd.concat([df2, df2.where(df2['max'].between(5,20))], axis=1)
```

output:

```
   Name  Age  min  max  cons  count  Name   Age   min   max  cons  count
0   tom   10    5   10     2      7   tom  10.0   5.0  10.0   2.0    7.0
1  nick   15   15   15     1      2  nick  15.0  15.0  15.0   1.0    2.0
2  juli   14   14   14     1      5  juli  14.0  14.0  14.0   1.0    5.0
3   tom   20   10   20     3      7   tom  20.0  10.0  20.0   3.0    7.0
4  juli   17   17   17     1      5  juli  17.0  17.0  17.0   1.0    5.0
5   tom   30   30   30     1      7   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
6  nick   19   19   19     1      2  nick  19.0  19.0  19.0   1.0    2.0
7  juli   24   24   29     2      5   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
8   tom    0    0    0     1      7   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
9  juli   76   76   76     1      5   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
```

For more bins:

```
bins = [(5,20), (25,40)]
out = pd.concat([df2]+[df2.where(df2['max'].between(a,b)) for a,b in bins], axis=1)
```

output:

```
   Name  Age  min  max  cons  count  Name   Age   min   max  cons  count  Name   Age   min   max  cons  count
0   tom   10    5   10     2      7   tom  10.0   5.0  10.0   2.0    7.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
1  nick   15   15   15     1      2  nick  15.0  15.0  15.0   1.0    2.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
2  juli   14   14   14     1      5  juli  14.0  14.0  14.0   1.0    5.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
3   tom   20   10   20     3      7   tom  20.0  10.0  20.0   3.0    7.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
4  juli   17   17   17     1      5  juli  17.0  17.0  17.0   1.0    5.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
5   tom   30   30   30     1      7   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   tom  30.0  30.0  30.0   1.0    7.0
6  nick   19   19   19     1      2  nick  19.0  19.0  19.0   1.0    2.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
7  juli   24   24   29     2      5   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN  juli  24.0  24.0  29.0   2.0    5.0
8   tom    0    0    0     1      7   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
9  juli   76   76   76     1      5   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but I think the output is incorrect for 4th row(3rd index) i.e., instead of tom,20,10,20,7,3 the output should have been tom,10,10,20,7,3 if I consider bin as 5<value<20 and not 5<=value<=20.
If I consider bin as 5<=value<=15 then the output should have been tom,10,10,20,7,3 but I'm getting as NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN

Comment: Because I want the max of the value falling in that bin for each and every consecutive group and not the max value across the df.

Comment: @UnetModel `between` can do any possibility with the `inclusive` argument, you can use `{"both", "neither", "left", "right"}`, pick the one you want ;)

Comment: Thank you, I understood the usage for "between" keyword but the above solution will work for max of bins considering the whole dataframe and not consecutive groups, for example I have [["tom", 20],["tom",10],["tom",7]], the consecutive group is for "tom" and in this if I consider bin as 5-15, then I should get max(bin) which will be ["tom",10] because it'll look in the original df group which is "tom" and falls in bin 5-15 i.e., it'll look in [["tom",10],["tom",7]], but in the above code it's yielding me NaN for 4th row because it is checking from "max" column from the whole df2.

Comment: Does my above explanation and doubt make sense or is it confusing? Because I'm trying to modify the df2 code to add the bins and max of each consecutive group but I'm unable to.